# Send more than one line to an executable using bash

Tags: bash, stdin

So python has a convenient function as part of `pwntools` where one can `sendline()` to an executable. How can I emulate this functionality in bash?

#### Example

```py
#whatever.py
x = input("First input please: ")
y = input("Second input please: ")
```

I know I can `echo "input1" | python3 whatever.py` to answer the first input, but I can't make it work multiline (`echo "input1\ninput2" | ...` doesn't work, and neither does `echo "input1"; echo "input2" | ...`).

Comment: In the bash shell, you'd need `echo -e` to interpret the `\n` as a newline. Or better use `printf '%s\n' input1 input2` - see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer in the abstract, since I suspect these are not the actual commands you're needing to use, but does `( echo "input1" ; echo "input2" ) | ...` or `{ echo "input1" ; echo "input2" } | ...` (with the parentheses/braces) work for your use case?

Comment: @frabjous: with `{ }` you need `;` or newline after second (echo) command; with `( )` you don't

Comment: @frabjous Parentheses work, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python script requires two lines of input on its standard input stream.  Any of the following would provide that:

1. Two calls to `echo` in a subshell:

   ```bsh
   ( echo 'line 1'; echo 'line 1' ) | python3 whatever.py
   ```
2. Two calls to `echo` in a compound command:

   ```bsh
   { echo 'line 1'; echo 'line 1'; } | python3 whatever.py
   ```
3. A single call to `echo` using the non-standard `-e` option to interpret the embedded `\n` as a literal newline:

   ```bsh
   echo -e 'line 1\nline 2' | python3 whatever.py
   ```
4. One call to `printf`, formatting each subsequent argument as its own line of output.  This would be more suitable for variable data than using `echo`, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).

   ```bsh
   printf '%s\n' 'line 1' 'line 2' | python3 whatever.py
   ```
5. Using a here-document redirection:

   ```bsh
   python3 whatever.py <<'END_INPUT'
   line 1
   line 2
   END_INPUT
   ```